# Moving files with a certain file name from one folder to another

Tags: file, directory

i currently have a folder containing thousands of 10-K financial reports.
All of these files are .txt files.

The files look like this:

20170103_10-K_edgar_data_1662618_0001376474-17-000004_1.txt

20170104_10-Q_edgar_data_886137_0000886137-17-000006_1.txt

20170106_10-K-A_edgar_data_1590496_0001477932-17-000065_1.txt

20170106_10-Q_edgar_data_1275187_0001275187-17-000005_1.txt

I only need files that are "10-K" files and contain a certain CIK-number.
e.g. only the files which contain the string "10-K_edgar_data" and the CIK-number "0001376474"

Is there a way to achieve this for multiple 10-K files with different CIK-numbers?

EDIT: I use Mac OS High Sierra. I also have python 2 & 3 and I use it with PyCharm. But for now I only know the absolute Python basics (I am still learning the language...)

Comment: what is the OS?

Comment: please consider adding more details. tell us about your os or programming language ( if you want to do it in a programe )